# Why linkedlist required when hash collision occur and Hashmap does not allow duplicate elements?

Tags: java

Why is a linkedlist required when hash collision occurs and `HashMap` does not allow duplicate elements? I was trying to understand following points in `HashMap`:

1. `HashMap` does not give order of elements. But following elements I am getting insertion order then `LinkedHashMap` is different with `HashMap`.

   ```
   Map<String, Integer>  ht2=new HashMap<String, Integer>();
   ht2.put("A", 20);
   ht2.put("B", 10);
   ht2.put("C", 30);
   ht2.put("D", 50);
   ht2.put("E", 40);
   ht2.put("F", 60);
   ht2.put("G", 70);

   for(Entry e:ht2.entrySet())
   {
       System.out.println(e.getKey() +"<<<key  HashMap value>>>"+e.getValue());
   }
   ```
2. `HashMap` does not allow duplicate keys , Yes I can get expected output. When we are storing object as a key we have to overwrite the equal method based on attribute, so same object or same object information will not be duplicate. So every bucket will have only one entry if entry same previous one will overwrite. I am not understanding how multiple entry are coming in a same bucket when collision occur it is overwriting the previous value. Why linked list is required here when duplicate are not allowing here. Please look into below example.

   ```
   HashMap<Employee, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<Employee, Integer>(4);        
   for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
       Employee myKey = new Employee(i,"XYZ",new Date());
       hashMap.put(myKey, i);
   }
   System.out.println("myKey Size ::"+hashMap.size());
   ```

Here I am creating 100 Employee object so 100 buckets are created. I can see when hashcode value printed different value. So how linked list are coming here and how multiple entry are going in to same bucket.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). - if you want to assign multiple values to a key, why don't you simply create a `Map<Key,Collection<Value>>`?

Comment: Because hashcodes are not unique.

Answer (score 2):

There is a different between the number of buckets and the number of entries in the `HashMap`.

Two keys of the `HashMap` may have the same `hashCode`, even if they are not equal to each other, which means both of them will be stored in the same bucket. Therefore the linked list (or some other structure that can hold multiple entries) is required.

Even two keys having different `hashCode` may be stored in the same bucket, since the number of buckets is much smaller than the number of possible `hashCode` values. For example, if the `HashMap` has 16 buckets, keys with `hashCode` 0 and 16 will be mapped to the same bucket. Therefore the bucket must be able to hold multiple entries.

The first part of your question is not clear. If you meant to ask why you see different iteration order in `HashMap` vs. `LinkedHashMap`, the reason is `HashMap` doesn't maintain insertion order, and `LinkedHashMap` does maintain insertion order. If for some input you are seeing an iteration order matching the insertion order in `HashMap`, that's just coincidence (depending on the buckets that the inserted keys happen to be mapped to).

Comment: First part of the question : As we know HashMap gives unordered elements and linked list gives insertion order elements. But how I am getting key and value as same order I have inserted in Hashmap using iteration as mentioned code above. 

           Second part of question : If two entry has same hashcode then how we will get the distinguish elements from bucket? Since we overwriting the equal method how chance there tow entry will have same hash code?

Comment: @user184182 `If two entry has same hashcode then how we will get the distinguish elements from bucket?` - by calling `equals`. If a.hashCode()==b.hashCode(), a.equals(b) can still be false.

Comment: @user184182 Regarding the insertion order and iteration order. HashMap iterates over the entries according to the order of the buckets. i.e., first you get the entries of the first bucket (if any exist), then the elements of the second bucket and so on (the iteration order within a single bucket depends on the implementation of that bucket - linked list or tree). If the keys you entered happen to be mapped to buckets in ascending order (for example, the first is mapped to bucket 2, the second to bucket 3 and the third to bucket 5), you'll see an iteration order identical to insertion order.

Comment: Hi, I was trying to replicate the scenario where HashCode collusion will occur and elements will store in LinkedList. But every time I can see when collusion occur that previous key value get replace from the bucket and new value store. Kindly give me an example how collusion occur and store new key value in Linkedlist or my previous key value will not replace by new key value.

Comment: @user184182 Try putting the keys A`` and BA in your HashMap. Both have `hashCode` of 2111 even though they are not equal to each other. Edit: the first key should have only two characters - remove the 3rd character.

Answer (score 2):

When a HashMap collision occurs, like you said in your question the .equals is involved.  The linked list is used like this:

1. If a collision occurs and the .equals returns true, then the old reference (if the references are not identical, of course) is replaced by the new one
2. If the .equals() returns false against the existing value and only one object is in the current bucket, the HashMap  inserts it to a linked list at index 0. Note that in java's standard HashMap implementation, the entries into this linked list are *entirely internal*, that is, you wouldn't even be able to access the list under normal circumstances
3. If there is more than one entry in the current bucket, it continues down the list until it finds a case where .equals() returns true on the existing object in the list and replaces, or it reaches the end of the list/bucket, in which case step 2 occurs

So you technically don't have to worry about the list, just make sure that your .hashcode minimizes the amount of collisions

Comment: It's actually not necessarily a linked list any more that holds​ multiple​ items in the same bucket; it could be a Red-Black tree.

Comment: @LewBloch yes, linked list is just a description for a data structure and is not Java specific. Although Entry<K, V> looks like a linkedlist implementation to me, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, indeed, a linked list is a data structure, and so is a red-black tree. They are different structures, as you may have inferred by their having different names, @null_pointers. While the structures themselves are not Java-specific, Java specifically uses them in its implementation of `HashMap`. You perhaps noticed that I'm fairly rigorous about how I spell things when I discuss general structures and that I don't use backticks for them, vs. how I spell out Java keywords and type names, using backticks. So I distinguish between a linked list and `LinkedList`.

Comment: I didn't know if that's what you were referring to, but I added a space as soon as I saw your comment.  I'll even make it lower case now just to clear up any remaining confusion;)

Comment: Hi, I was trying to replicate the scenario where HashCode collusion will occur and elements will store in LinkedList. But every time I can see when collusion occur that previous key value get replace from the bucket and new value store. Kindly give me an example how collusion occur and store new key value in Linkedlist or my previous key value will not replace by new key value.

Comment: @user184182 see my comment where I say that "in java's standard HashMap implementation, the entries into this linked list are entirely internal, that is, you wouldn't even be able to access the list under normal circumstances" is where you are confused.

Comment: @user184182 in the debugger look at the "next" value in a hashmap entry that you forced a collision with